# How to check SearchController is active or not before click UITableview cell using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am implementing `SearchController` with `tableview` data. Here, Once searched particular data after that clicking search result cell to moving another detail page. Now, If I comeback to main view controller search controller showing without dismissing. I tried below code Its working fine for detail to main viewcontroller scenario but If I click cell without search text then its making crash. How to fix it?

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

  let section = isFiltering ? filteredSections[indexPath.section] : sections[indexPath.section] // without search text I am getting index out of range issue
        let item = section.result[indexPath.row]

                let detailsVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "detailviewcontroller") as! DetailViewController
                let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: detailsVC)
                self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)


            // Search Dismiss - without search text if click tableview cell I am getting crash 
            // MARK: Validate SearchController isActive or Not.
        if searchController != nil {
            // Get rid of searchController
            searchController.searchBar.endEditing(true)
            searchController.isActive = false
            searchController.dismiss(animated: true) { /* */ }
        }
        }
```

Comment: will you post the crash log here?

Comment: @SureshMopidevi `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value` at the line  `searchController.isActive = false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because your searchController is not initiated yet. Just check for `searchController != nil` first.

Comment: you saved my time LOL. I did't thinked about it. Thanks

Comment: I have one issue by above solution, If search controller empty then if click cell I am getting `Fatal error: Index out of range` at this `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         let section = isFiltering ? filteredSections[indexPath.section] : sections[indexPath.section] }`

Comment: @TestApp can you edit your question and provide code and screenshots?

Comment: I updated please check it. My scenario, with text to go main and comeback previous it should dismiss and without text tableview cell click it will allow to move next viewcontroller. both need to implement it

Comment: if search active = true but search array empty (it mean search.text == "") that time occurring crash @tara tandel

Comment: let me check if I get that right. you search something you fill an array called 'filteredSections' then you click on one of them go to a new VC then using the back button you come back to the previous VC. your results are still showing but the array is empty?

Comment: No. Thats is not an issue. Scenario 1. Without search controller active tableview cell click to move details page - working fine. 2. Search controller is active with search result to cell click move details - working fine. 3. SearchController is active without any search text in search bar now if I click it refer  filteredSections and nothing array items so that I am getting index out of range crash. Now, how to check if search controller == active && empty need to call  sections array. @tara tandel

Comment: how to validate if search controller active == true but there is nothing text entered into search.textbox so this time need to refer section array. `isFiltering ? filteredSections[indexPath.section] : sections[indexPath.section]` isFiltering already active but I didn't type nothing text into search box. now as per this line filter array calling and making crash. how to handle this?

Comment: how do you populate isFiltering variable ?

Comment: you use this function func searchBarIsEmpty() -> Bool {
  // Returns true if the text is empty or nil
  return searchController?.searchBar?.text?.isEmpty ?? true
} to check if it is empty or not

Comment: by default globally I am using var isFiltering = false but once search button click I am enabling var isFiltering = true. This is the problem @tara tandel

Comment: Mentioning my comment above . on didSelectRowAt method first set isFiltering like this isFiltering = searchBarIsEmpty()

Comment: I used this but not working. Please update your answer. @tara tandel

Comment: can you tell me what is the function returning ?

Comment: I mean the function I wrote. can you use a break point and log the returning ?

Comment: if I do break point its triggered into that function. @tara tandel

Comment: `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
 isFiltering = !searchBarIsEmpty() // use the break point here
  let section = isFiltering ? filteredSections[indexPath.section] : sections[indexPath.section] // without search text I am getting index out of range issue
        let item = section.result[indexPath.row]

                let detailsVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "detailviewcontroller") as! DetailViewController  ................`
             use the breakpoint on the line I put a comment

Comment: on the console(the black area on the right bottom part of the Xcode) write: po searchBarIsEmpty() . and see if it is true of false. it should be true or nil

Comment: Buddy :) first of all why I need to assign ` isFiltering = !searchBarIsEmpty()` its already assigned for searchbar active control right. Just simply how can I validate if searchbar text empty and isFiltering == true need to assign normal array (section) (not to filteraarry).